# Scala, why can't underscore function syntax infer type?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm new to scala and I've stumbled upon some weird cases where type inference does not work as expected. for example, this does not compile:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .map(if _ > 3 then "foo" else "bar")
```

the compiler explicitly states it can't infer the type of _$1 which I take to be the first parameter of the function the syntax above desugars to.

somewhat frustratingly, the below code compiles just fine, even with no type annotation:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .map{ n => if n > 3 then "foo" else "bar"}
```

clearly there's something I'm not grasping about how _ desugars. can somebody clue me in on what's missing?

Comment: Probably because it expaned like this: `map { if ((x => x) > 3)` - really, don't use the `_` it is just asking for troubles.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That is really annoying :(. What OP expected is more intuitive imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis:

```scala
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .map(if (_) > 3 then "foo" else "bar")
```

See it [working](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vgRbjB0PR5GTjsdGkabSbg) for Scala 3.

Or more "canonical" version working both for [Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n4RHpUKCQFSB7d0vkfK8qg) and [Scala 2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PBdDpMZOSMibC91uT52Fog) and mentioned in Scala 2.11 [spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions):

| placeholder syntax. | equivalent anonymous function |
| --- | --- |
| _ + 1 | x => x + 1 |
| _ * _ | (x1, x2) => x1 * x2 |
| (_: Int) * 2 | (x: Int) => (x: Int) * 2 |
| if (_) x else y | z => if (z) x else y |
| _.map(f) | x => x.map(f) |
| _.map( _ + 1) | x => x.map(y => y + 1) |

```scala
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  .map(_ > 3)
  .map(if (_) "foo" else "bar")
```